# How to add test settings file to a solution

Tags: c#, testing, settings

I have a test settings file that lists out the `<DeploymentItem>`s. I want to use this file for my test runs. However when I add it to the solution using "Add Existing item", it says

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'deployment item 'c:\myschema.xsd'' Key being added: 'deployment item 'c:\myschema.xsd'
```

What does this mean? How do I undo it and add my settings?

Comment: Usually the testsettings file is controlled via the Test->Edit Test Settings menu. Do you see it listed there? Also, open the .sln file in notepad and see if your testsettings file is already referenced.

Answer (score 0):

It happened that there were duplicate deployment items in the Test Settings xml file.